# Joomla(2.5) regional content

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

Is there joomla component or something else which allow to divide site by user city?(....which work with zoo component)
I want to show different content for each city or to show default content.

Also url change by city:
site.ru/chicago
site.ru/dallas
or
dallas.site.ru
chicago.site.ru

Open site -> choose my city -> and i see all content for my city(pages,products...)

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this `http://extensions.joomla.org/extension/metamod`
or use GeoIp libary and solve that programmaticly.